# Mysqli Class Always returns NULL for results with one var passed through

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli, prepared-statement

Every time I call a query with my class for select * from table where blank=blank it always comes up "NULL" on a var_dump for the results at the end of the class. I'm still stuck on this and don't know why it's doing it, but it sends no responses for sure, because I'm getting nothing back.

mysqli.class.php

```
<?php
class DATABASE
{
//set up variables only for this class
private $db_host;
private $db_user;
private $db_pass;
private $db_name;
private $connection;
private $paramaters = array();
private $results = array();
private $numrows;

//call connection on call of class
public function __construct($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name)
{
    $this->host = $db_host;
    $this->user = $db_user;
    $this->pass = $db_pass;
    $this->name = $db_name;
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name) or die('There was a problem connecting to the database! Error #: '. $this->mysqli->connect_errno);
}
//close mysqli connection on class close
public function __destruct()
{
    $this->mysqli->close();
}
//query
public function select($fields, $table, $where, $whereVal, $type, $orderByVal, $ASDESC, $limitVal, $sets, $setVal)
{
    switch($type)
    {
        case "regular":
            if ($where == null)
            {
                $queryPre = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table;
                $querySuff = "";
            } else {
                $queryPre = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table;
                $querySuff = " WHERE " . $where . " = ?";
            }
            break;
        case "orderByLimit":
            $queryPre = "SELECT " . $fields . " FROM " . $table;
            $querySuff = " ORDER BY " . $orderByVal . " " . $ASDESC . " LIMIT " . $limitVal;
            break;
        case "update":
            if ($where == null)
            {
                $queryPre = "UPDATE " . $table;
                //need for loop for multiple sets, check for is_array and do multiple if so.
                $querySuff = " SET " . $sets . " = " . $setVal;
            } else {
                $queryPre = "UPDATE " . $table;
                //need for loop for multiple sets, check for is_array and do multiple if so.
                $querySuff = " SET " . $sets . " = " . $setVal . " WHERE " . $where . " = ?";
            }
            break;
        case "insert":
            if ($sets == null)
            {
                $queryPre = "INSERT INTO " . $table;
                $querySuff = " VALUES(" . setVal . ")";
            } else {
                $queryPre = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (" . $sets . ")";
                $querySuff = " VALUES(" . setVal . ")";
            }
        case "delete":
            if ($where == null)
            {
                $queryPre = "DELETE FROM " . $table;
                $querySuff = "";
            } else {
                $queryPre = "DELETE FROM " . $table;
                $querySuff = " WHERE " . $where . " = ?";
            }
    }
    //$sql = $queryPre . "" . $querySuff; 
    //var_dump($sql);
    //exit;
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($queryPre . "" . $querySuff) or die('There was a problem preparing the Query! Error#: '. $this->mysqli->errno); 
    if ($whereVal == null)
    {
        $stmt = $this->bindVars($stmt,$setVal);
    } else {
        $stmt = $this->bindVars($stmt,$whereVal);
    }
    $stmt->execute();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata();

    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field())
    {
        $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
    }
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) 
    {
        $x = array();
        foreach($row as $key => $val)
        {
            $x[$key] = $val;
        }
        $results[] = $x;
    }
    $stmt->close();
    //var_dump($results);
    if ($results == "" || $results == NULL)
    {
        return null;
    } else {
        return $results;
    }
}
private function bindVars($stmt,$params) 
{
    if ($params != null) 
    {
        $types = '';
        //initial sting with types
        if (is_array($params))
        {
            foreach($params as $param)
            {
                //for each element, determine type and add
                if(is_int($param))
                {
                    $types .= 'i'; //integer
                } elseif (is_float($param)) 
                {
                    $types .= 'd'; //double
                } elseif (is_string($param))
                {
                    $types .= 's'; //string
                } else {
                    $types .= 'b'; //blob and unknown
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (is_int($params))
            {
                $types = 'i';
            } elseif (is_float($params))
            {
                $types = 'd';
            } elseif (is_string($params))
            {
                $types = 's';
            } else {
                $types = 'b';
            }               
        }
        $bind_names[] = $types;
        if (is_array($params))
        {
            //go through incoming params and added em to array
            for ($i=0; $i<count($params);$i++)
            {
                //give them an arbitrary name
                $bind_name = 'bind' . $i;
                //add the parameter to the variable variable
                $$bind_name = $params[$i];
                //now associate the variable as an element in an array
                $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;               
            }
        } else {
            $int0 = 0;
            $bind_name = 'bind' . $int0;
            $$bind_name = $params;
            $bind_names[] = &$$bind_name;
        }
        call_user_func_array(array($stmt,'bind_param'),$bind_names);
    }
    return $stmt; //return the bound statement
}
}
?>
```

example to call and check fields - process_availability.php:

```
<?php
//require necessary files
require('../config/dbconfig.php');
include('../classes/mysqli.class.php');
//initiate connection
$mysqli = new DATABASE($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
//take type of check
$checktype = $_POST['type'];

//check the user name
if ($checktype == "username") {
//change post to variable
$username = $_POST['username'];
//check if user name is empty
if ($username == "") {
    $validuser = array("empty", "false");
    echo implode(',', $validuser);
    exit;
}
//if user name is more characters than 30
if (strlen($username) > 30) {
    $validuser = array("max", "false");
    echo implode(',', $validuser);
    exit;
}
//search for same user name in database
$resultsU = $mysqli->select('*','users','username',$username,'regular',null,null,null,null,null);
//var_dump($resultsU);
if (is_array($resultsU))
{
var_dump($resultsU);
    foreach($resultsU as $rowU)
    {
        //return results
        if($rowU['username'] == "" || $rowU['username'] == NULL)
        {
            //user name is blank
            $validuser = array("yes", "true");
            echo implode(',', $validuser);
            exit;
        }
        else {
            //username is not blank, so it's taken
            $validuser = array("no", "false");
            echo implode(',', $validuser);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And just to show what I'm actually doing with the information, here is a PART of the java (just handles username mostly, there is a ton more for email, ect not included):
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJVLE/)

And, of coarse, the link to the page: [page link](http://hardcoregamesusa.com/portal/register.php)

I've been fixing other things on here, and on a technicality it works. I get a response if there IS something in the database that matches the username i type, but if there is no match, for some reason it doesn't respond at all.....

Specifically...right at the bottom of the 2nd to last function in the class:

```
$stmt->close(); 
//var_dump($results); 
if ($results == "" || $results == NULL) 
{ 
    return null; 
} else { 
    return $results; 
}
```

Comment: *sigh* Why do so many people seem to feel that MySQLi needs a wrapper class? Anyway, can you specify where in that huge code block you are actually having the problem? Which `var_dump()` on which line shows you `NULL`?

Comment: OK, well what are expecting instead of `NULL`? You never initialised `$results` as an array, you just push items onto it when you are processing the database results. So if there are no results, `$results` will be undefined, which in PHP is effectively `NULL`. Plus your code is designed so that if there are no results the `select()` method returns `NULL`, and your process_availability.php file only outputs anything `if (is_array($resultsU))` - which obviously it won't be, because there were no results, so `select()` returns `NULL`.

Comment: In the very top of the class, $results = array(); That's been there, unless there is another way to initialize $results as an array.

Comment: Yes but that's a private property, you would have to access if through `$this->results` and not just `$results`. But even so, that alone wont fix it - the function will still return `NULL` if there are no results, because `array() == NULL`. You should put `$results = array();` at the top of the `select()` method. You should also remove the `if / else` block at the end and simply `return $results;` and remove the `if (is_array($resultsU))` condition from process_availability.php

Comment: Alright, removed private $results, put $results = array(); right after calling select function, and removed if/else and just put return $results. Also removed is_array, but now if there is nothing in the db it just returns "array(0) {};"

Comment: I'm not sure what else you are expecting. If there are no results, what do you *want* to return?

Comment: That's why I was returning null, I just need to parse it on the process page, it's just checking if a username already exists or not, so if it comes back blank, they need to be able to register it. I'm just not getting the logic to set it up I guess....

Comment: Oh *right* I see where you're going with this. Well, what I would do is return the results in JSON. So if there are no results you will still return an empty array to Javascript which will still parse correctly as an array. That way in JS you can just check `if (result.length < 1) { /* username is free */ }`. Although actually you don't even need to return the results, you just need to return `1` (if the username exists) or `0` if it doesn't. Then you can just evaluate the returned string as a boolean.

Comment: Only issue with boolean is that if I ever need the results I can't really hardcode that into the class, otherwise I wasted the class. Is there something similiar to json in php that I can keep in PHP and pass? Or maybe a more effecient way to pass null if it is null and check with what I got?

Comment: You don't need to hard code it into the class, just do it in the code in process_availability.php

Comment: How would I return 0 or 1 in process_availibility? I thought the return was dependent on the query.

Comment: Well, for example, on the line immediately below `$resultsU = $mysqli->select(...`. You could just do: `echo (count($resultsU) > 0) ? 0 : 1;`

Comment: Dude, you are my hero. Could you put that in an answer for other people who do stupid stuff like me? lol.

Comment: I think that answer sums up the key points from this thread, let me know if you want me to add anything else to it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are returning no results to the client, you need to indicate to the client that this is what you have done, and the code shown above simply outputs nothing in this case. While it is easily possible to handle this empty response correctly on the client side a better solution would be to do one of the following:

- If you need the data from the result, `json_encode()` the results before sending them back to the client. This would mean that if the were no results you would return an empty array, but it would still be valid JSON and crucially you can easily check whether the result array is empty on the client side using `result.length`.
- If you *don't* actually need the result data and all you need is to determine whether there were any results, you can simply return a 1 or a 0. This kind of boolean response takes minimal bandwidth and minimal processing, and the best thing about it is all you need to do is evaluate it as a boolean on the client side - i.e. `if (result) { /* do stuff */ }`